# Bazel test not generating bazel-testlogs folder

Tags: testing, build, bazel

I am running bazel test on a directory using the below command:

```
bazel test //folder-name/... --cache_test_results=no
```

It gives an output like this:

```
Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
There were tests whose specified size is too big. Use the --test_verbose_timeout_warnings command line option to see which ones these are.
All tests passed but there were other errors during the build.
```

This returns an exit status code of 0.

Not related to this question but I would have expected an exit status code of 1 since build failed (as per: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.21.0/guide.html#what-exit-code-will-i-get for build failure it should return exit code 1)

Now, after running the above command, the bazel-testlogs folder is missing, it only generates bazel-out folder and skips bazel-testlogs folder.

However, on running with flag build_tests_only, it is creating bazel-testlogs.

```
bazel test --build_tests_only //folder-name/... --cache_test_results=no
```

I would like to skip --build_tests_only flag, so as to detect any build related errors despite it not being in tests and have the bazel-testlogs folder. Can someone please help in this like why bazel-testlogs folder is missing and how can I have that?

Comment: 1. What Bazel version are you using?
2. Is Bazel printing any messages about "convenience symlink(s)"?

Comment: 1. I am using bazel version: 6.2.1
2. Yes, I later got one of these github issue, where, it addresses the same issue: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/17081

I am now using the path: bazel-out/**/testlogs/** , this seems to be working for me. Earlier I was using symlink path of bazel-testlogs, which seems to be removed most likely from version 6.x.

Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use path of bazel-testlogs to analyse the test logs/results. Apparently, the folder bazel-testlogs is just a symlink of testlogs folder present in bazel-out. So, changing the path where analysis was done from bazel-testlogs to bazel-out/**/testlogs/* worked. Also, the version of bazel that I am using is 6.2.1.

This issue is from version 6.x as also raised over here:  https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/17081

So, in this scenario, symlink path can be avoided.

Comment: A better approach will be to get rid of even bazel-out and use a direct path, because bazel-out is also a symlink path.